# Django collectstatic not pushing to AWS S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't push my local files to amazon S3 using django 'collectstatic'.

My settings.py, all the settings that may be relevant:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
INSTALLED_APPS += ('storages',)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWSAccessKeyId']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWSSecretKey']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
```

If I run collectsatic with these settings, I get the error:

```
0 static files copied, 139 unmodified.
```

If I change the STATIC_ROOT to "/" (this is how I'd like it to be, given the folder distribution in the Amazon Bucket), I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/css'
```

Please help, I've run out of ideas. I've double-checked the credentials and I've also tried to run it from heroku.

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

Same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), you'll need to add

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

to your settings file.

Comment: I can't believed I missed something that obvious. However, it's weird cause it worked on the first deploy a month ago. Anyway, thanks.